# How to Timing out java.sql.ResultSet

Tags: java, database, plsql, timeout

The PL/SQl cursor was getting hanged due to some reason, this makes my app to hang when try to loop through the `ResultSet`.

Is there a way to handle this, like timing out the resultset if the database hangs?

Answer (score 2):

There is a setQueryTimeout(int) on the java.sql.Statement interface. You should call it before invoking the executeQuery().

You can also asynchronously cancel a running query by calling cancel() on the Statement too.

**Edit:** Oracle jdbc driver version 6 supports these methods for sure, as I'm using it in one of my projects.

Comment: But check that your JDBC driver really supports this feature as it is optional for ResultSets

Comment: @GáborHargitai how can I check that? Specifically for the DB2 Universal JDBC Driver Provider, I'm googling like crazy and finding no documentation that helps me :(

Comment: Using `queryTimeout` doesn't work in all cases. For example if the `ResultSet` is returned as an output parameter in a `StoredProcedure`. The timeout is only respected in the `CallableStatement.execute()` methods